# Generation of .yml file with springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin doesn't escape date

Tags: java, spring, swagger, openapi, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I'm using the plugin `springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin` as described in https://springdoc.org/#plugins.

I'm using this plugin to create my `.yml` file based on the swagger annotations on my controllers and dto's.

I can generate the `.yml` file successfully. But the only thing that's not correct is the 'date' values. These are not within quotes ("").

So for example this is how my generated `.yml` file looks like:

```
...
createdAt: 2022-02-24T11:43:38Z
...
```

But I expect date values to be within quotes, like:

```
...
createdAt: "2022-02-24T11:43:38Z"
...
```

The class I've applied the annotation on:

```
public class UserDto {

    @Schema(format = "date-time")
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;

}
```

Does anyone have any idea what's wrong, or how I can fix this?

Thank you!